# kotlinc -script with multiple files

Tags: kotlin, module, package, kotlinc

I have a Kotlin script which I'm using for testing.
In order to run it quickly, I'm using `kotlinc -script` to evaluate it which prints me the result straight away in the console.

Now, when the script becomes big enough, I want to split it into different submodules/packages. Is it possible to evaluate a script with multiple files with `kotlinc`?

Note, the setup is only intended for testing purposes that's the reason I don't want to compile it, to avoid an extra step. Imagine doing it stright from the console and you don't want to set up a project with Gradle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [kscript](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript) is the answer.

1. Install [kscript](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript)
2. Import required file: `//INCLUDE directory/requiredFile.kts`
3. You can call functions from the `requiredFile.kts` now.
4. Run your file with kscript `./mainScript.kts`, you may need to `chmod +x mainScript.kts`

If anyone knows how to do it directly with `kotlinc` let me know.